# Type error during training of Decision Tree model in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, model, decision-tree

I have code and error like below, where is the mistake ? What can I do? when i use this code for other model everything was good:

```
X_DT = data_modelling.loc[:, data.columns != "wine_type"]
y_DT = data_modelling.loc[:, data.columns == "wine_type"]

#Loop to find optimal train / test split
for k in range(1, 10):
    X_train_DT, X_test_DT, y_train_DT, y_test_DT = train_test_split(X_DT,
                                                                    y_DT,
                                                                    test_size = 0.1*k,
                                                                    random_state = 777)
    
    
    DT = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = "gini",
                                splitter = "random",
                                max_depth = 12,
                                min_samples_split = 2,
                                min_samples_leaf = 3,
                                max_features = sqrt)
    DT.fit(X = X_train_DT, y = y_train_DT)
    
    prediction_train_DT = DT.predict(X_train_DT)
    #Prediction on test dataset
    prediction_test_DT = DT.predict(X_test_DT)
    
    #Printing results
    print(f"test: {k/10}, Train AUC:", round(roc_auc_score(y_train_DT, prediction_train_DT), 3),
          "Test AUC:", round(roc_auc_score(y_test_DT, prediction_test_DT), 3))
```

and mistake:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ufunc' and 'float'

screen of error :
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to include a sample of `X_train_DT` and `y_train_DT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max_features = sqrt` should be `max_features = 'sqrt'`.